# Implementing couchbase offline sync in cordova project

Tags: cordova, couchbase

I want to implement the offline sync feature in my hybrid app (cordova framework) & i explored about couchbase for that but i didn't get any proper documentation for that. Some question in my mind:

1. I have installed the cordova couchbase-lite phonegap plugin, but what to do now.
2. How to use sync gateway(configuring the 'sync-gateway-config.json' file).
3. I have downloaded the couchbase server on my system, but how to connect it with my app.

So if any of the member of this group have any idea about how i implement this offline support to my hybrid app then please let me know about that.

You can also write mail to me on this address: paritosh.yadav.237@gmail.com